# how to make client and server to develop independently?

Tags: architecture, networking, design-patterns

Currently,  all i want to do is rapid prototyping of Tower-Defense-Like game, which means that i just need write client code only,single player, play with AI system. but shortly afterwards, maybe it's going to be a multiplayer game .
my question is how can i design my game architecture suited for singleplayer mode firstly, and for multiplayer mode latterly, it doesn't mess up my previous effort(single player only). any design pattern, or architecture , or hint?

I really appreciate for your answer, thank your guys in advance.
Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

Use a [model-view-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.

- Your Model is the current state of your game (how the map looks, which enemy is where, which tower is where, etc.)
- Your View is your graphics engine which visualizes the Model to the player
- Your Controllers are the game mechanics (which spawn enemies and make towers shoot at them) and the input handler for the player's commands.

Encapsulate all these modules against each other so that they interact with each other only through method calls. They should act as total black boxes to each other and make no assumptions about the implementation details of each other ("[Loose Coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling)").

Now if you want to make the game multiplayer, you can just add the network output as another View and the network input as another Controller.

Comment: hi, thank your reply, i don't think mvc is right way to do this, it's one kind of decouple way.  maybe i need to abstract user input and network input. after that, it convenient for test or debuging

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it the other way around...
It cost nothing to think on it as if it'd be already an online game by:

- having your logic isolated and comunicating with it via API: The point here is to be sure you only need to add server conection and a gateway on your app to do the same you do now against a real server. In MP games, the logic has to be in the server, in this case, if your logic lies out of the "scene" (in an isolated standalone module) it'll work exactly as a MP would do, but without network stuff
- separate states: In online games you need different states (usually) pointing to different endpoints or connected to sockets (your game-browse loby could use API calls but your game UDP sockets) this is not possible if your game states are all in a gigant switch/nested ifs. Build a [StateMachine](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fgamedevgeek.com%2Ftutorials%2Fmanaging-game-states-in-c%2F&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGmy49193Nc23bmbdrRLH3UdYKWRw) so you can switch between scenes and treat them as indepentent logic applications.

Once your game is done, you only have to write your server connection stuff and face the sincronization/connection issues

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of patterns that help here. The first one is the **Command** design pattern, where instead of directly coding to hardcoded keys you create objects that can operated. This is very useful for reconfiguring input controls or adding AI to control characters. It also makes it easy to send the input to other computers (since you don't care where the input came from).

This is very well explained in [this](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/command.html) chapter of the **Game Design Patterns** book which you can read online.

Another pattern that is useful is a logic/view architecture that uses events to communicate between the layers. Again the logic layer does not care where the input comes from. A great explanation of this architecture is in the second chapter of the **Game Coding Complete** book (where he talks in general about the game engine architecture) as well as in the implementation.